# What is a word that means "something that seems true, but isn't?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been looking for a general word to define an idea that seems true, but simply isn't.

A simple example: "The Earth is flat."  If all you know is the world outside your window, and you've never done any basic experiments, read books, or seen photos to the contrary, this seems like a reasonable explanation.  But it doesn't take too much more examination to find out that it  just isn't so.

The key point here is that it's something *a reasonable person could reasonably believe*.

The closest I've come to what I'm looking for is "verisimilitude."  I looked at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415707/something-that-sounds-good-but-has-no-true-meaning), but it seems to me that words like "spurious" or "nonsense" seem to imply some ill-intent to deceive, which is not what I'm after.  (Or maybe it's more a concept than a word, and that's ok too, if anyone has thoughts on that.)

Comment: "Illusory" might be closer...

Comment: I was about to compose an answer based on *illusory*, believing it to be the best fit to the question, but I cede to @Dave Kanter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is another word for a false belief or opinion on something that people hold true and repeat because they have heard it repeated so many times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297877/what-is-another-word-for-a-false-belief-or-opinion-on-something-that-people-hold) (misbelief, misconception, false impression, fallacy, false notion, old wives' tale, urban myth/legend ... delusion ...).

Comment: Or this: [What is a word to describe one's thoughts that sound logical and reasonable, but aren't?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532138/what-is-a-word-to-describe-ones-thoughts-that-sound-logical-and-reasonable-but/532140#532140) (specious; illusional)

Comment: For a noun, I suggest [**canard**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/canard).

Comment: "Canard" seems to me to imply an intention to deceive.  "Misconception" is a good one.

Comment: There are [**just-so stories**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-so_story), though they tend to be specifically about humans or animals, not about things in general.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought about this for a while...why I think that page doesn't answer my question is because it applies to the belief.  I'm trying to get to the thing that is believed.  So according to an old wives' tale, for many centuries people believed the world was flat.  What is word for the false belief (maybe that's the phrase!) itself?  It only becomes a "misconception" when given a certain context.

Comment: But 'What is another word for a false belief?' is then the same question, a duplicate.

Comment: So @EdwinAshworth I'm not saying it isn't, but there are two reasons I hesitate.  The first the "false belief" question is held true because people have heard it repeated so many times.  The second is that you would have to *know* it was a misconception, for "misconception" to work -- but you don't which is what you believe what you do.  But then...maybe such a context just doesn't exist.  It's a truth until it's proved a falsehood.

Comment: You may just be heading for 'paradox' then: [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradox#:~:text=1%20%3A%20a%20tenet%20contrary%20to,that%20at%20first%20seems%20true)] << **paradox**
... 
2a: a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is perhaps true >> [[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradox)]  allows the 'is true' subsense: << **paradox** (1)  a seemingly absurd or self-contradictory statement that is or may be true: ...>>. Obviously, if T is true, T' is not true.

Comment: Or "Tautology."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you spool one of these comments into an answer?  I'm going with "misconception" although somehow I suspect that's still not quite it.

Comment: I almost never 'answer' when I've close-voted as what I consider to be a duplicate. I'd say that the 'flat-Earth theory' was very plausible until mechanics (including gravitation) and optical astronomy had developed, especially if one lived far from the sea. It seems fair to consider the 'spheroidal planet' notion a paradox at that time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't delete the question.  Mark it as a duplicate, maybe?

Comment: @jimm101 it is, because I do believe "specious" is the word I'm looking for!  Thank you!  Please submit as an answer and the points are yours!

Answer (score 1):

**Seemingly** works well for the given context.

> appearing to be something, especially when this is not true:

*He remains confident and seemingly untroubled by his recent problems.*

[Cambridge]

You could this say: *The earth is **seemingly** flat.* (which it isn't in reality.)

Comment: I like the idea of "seemingly true."  That might be it...

Answer (score 0):

I would use *ostensibly*.

OED : as appears or is stated to be true, though not necessarily so

Comment: But I suppose in my situation the real truth may not be known.

Comment: In the context in which I ask the question, the real truth may not be known.  Or is not known.